# Can my LSTM model learn feature engineering on its own?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, feature-engineering

I have a timeseries dataset and I am training an LSTM model on it to perform multiclass classification.

My dataset has 7 columns => x1,x2,x3....x7

And has 4 labels => f1,f2,f3,f4

Since I have domain knowledge over my dataset, I know exactly what feature engineering needs to be done.

for example, I need to create 4 new features from my current features by applying some rules on each row:-

1. newx1 is created by => if (x2==x3) then 1, else 0
2. newx2 is created by => if (x1==x4 and x1>x5) then 1, else 0
3. newx3 is created by => if ((x1-x6)/x1>x7) then 1, else 0
4. newx4 is created by => if ((x6-x1)x1/>x7) then 1. else 0

I am getting 100% accuracy on test data if I train my LSTM model on newx1, newx2, newx3, newx4.

However, training it on the  original features (x1,x2....x7) I am getting reduced accuracy of 85-90% accuracy on test data.

The problem I am trying to solve requires me to have greater than 99% accuracy, so it won't suffice to have just 90% accuracy.

I was wondering if somehow my LSTM model can learn the rules for feature engineering on its own or do I have to change my model ?

Note: I can not apply the feature engineering rules manually because I am training the LSTM model on multiple datasets and each dataset will require its own feature engineering rules. I want to keep it as generic as possible.

LSTM model :-

````
def create_lstm_model(MaxTimeslice, H, LR, num_classes, dropout_rate=0.1, l2_reg=0.001):

    ip = Input(shape=(MaxTimeslice, H))
    x = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout_rate, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg))(ip)
    x = LSTM(16, dropout=dropout_rate, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg))(x)
    
   
    x = Dense(units=16, activation='relu')(x)
    multiclass_output = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=ip, outputs=multiclass_output)

    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"],
                  optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=LR))

    return model
```
````

Comment: How many samples are typically in your timeseries? And are your original variables continuous, discrete or boolean values? If you convert 7 continuous features to 4 boolean features you are massively reducing the parameter space. You only have 2^4 = 16 unique feature combinations, so depending on the number of samples in your timeseries it could simply be that after the transformation your training and test set have significantly overlapping sequences. The 100% accuracy is suspicious!